# Is this Discounted Cumulative Gain (DCG) formula problematic?

Tags: search-engine, information-retrieval

I read the wikipedia page about DCG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cumulative_gain

It shows that below formula can be used to define DCG.

[image]

But this formula makes me confused.

Let's say we have three documents whose relevance scores are 2, 5, and 1

Apparently, the best ranking is [5, 2, 1]. The DCG is 7.63

But the DCG of ranking of [2, 5, 1] is also 7.63. I think the DCG of this ranking is supposed to be less than 7.63

Is that formula problematic? Or did I miss something? May I change "log2(i)" to "log2(i+1)" in my application?

Thanks.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming (code) or programmers tools as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: In any case, please use another tag for this: [tag:dcg] is already taken!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about statistics formula and not about programming.